# Just adding a `cv2.imread` will make the inference time increased 80% in jetson nano though the imread result not used

Tags: python, opencv, benchmarking, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson-nano

ENVIRON:

1. jetson nano 4g
2. docker image: nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-ml:r32.7.1-py3

here’s my callback code, it's a main function.

```
pad_img = np.load('./data_640x384_batch1_nonorm.npy')
def my_callback():
    # cv2.imread("./00041.jpg")
    astart = time.time()
    runner._infer(pad_img)
    aend = time.time()
    
    runner_time = aend - astart
    print("runner time is %.3f"%(runner_time))
    return
```

the runner time is 0.014 and when comment out the cv2.imread("./00041.jpg"), the runner time will be 0.026, it is realy weird, hope someone can figure me out.

the complete code is put [here](https://github.com/igo312/Case_for_Bug/blob/main/cv2Imread_make_infer_slow.case.py)

---

**What I HAVE DONE**

there is no bug in the `class RUNNER`, no need to pay too much attention on it.

And when I  put load and infer process in a  main function like following, it will not effect the infer time.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    batch_size = 1
    execution_time = 400

    engine_path = args.engine_path
    engine = _get_engine(engine_path)

    context = RUNNER(engine, batch_size)

    temp = cv2.imread('./00041.jpg')
    temp = cv2.cvtColor(temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 
    img = np.load('./data_640x384_batch1_nonorm.npy')

    print("start speed test")
    
    for _ in range(int(execution_time/batch_size)):
        astart = time.time()
        result = context._infer(img)
        aend = time.time()
        print(aend-astart)
```

In addition, when I use `sudo jetson_clocks`, it also does not effect the infer time. But I wanna why and `sudo jetson_clocks` is not reconmended in my project.

upgrade `opencv` is also not allowed.

Comment: more work takes more time to execute. you should have expected this outcome when you added `imread()`. please perform more accurate timing measurements. that means: not just one, not with `time.time()`